# Auto update 2 tables after linking them

Tags: vertica

I have one table with data say 100 records(1st table).

I create a blank table(2nd table).

I want to link or copy the data from the first table into the new blank table.

When the 1st table is updated , this updation should happen in the 2nd table also.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "link"?

Comment: Ok maybe I might have used a wrong word. I have an existing table with data. I create a new table (empty). The data present in the existing table should be in the new table. And when I update the existing table and when more records are added to the existing table, it should happen in the new table also. This is my scenario. is this possible?

Comment: I don't see why a view wouldn't accomplish what your trying to do.

Comment: Yes. I know that view will do. I am asking if it is possible to do in tables.

Answer (score 1):

Hy @DrewRose,
 I think what you are looking for is a trigger event, well Vertica does not support triggers! 

 What to use to give business logic in Vertica:

- Vertica supports and provides ODBC/JDBC/ADO.NET interfaces.
- Vertica provides SDK for UDF on C/C++ and R-language

  *Remeber that Vertica is MPP and is not fit for a high transactional environment, this may slow down your database.*

  **How would i do it !**
- 1- i would check to see if Vertica does not carry already a tool to
  fix this for me !

**For example :** 
*- if you table is not a huge table you can use the **MERGE Statement**  from vertica, is a native function and is quite fast. Take a look at this [link](https://my.vertica.com/docs/CE/6.0.1/HTML/index.htm#17319.htm) to see it in more detail.*

- 2- i would try to fix this logic at loading time. See the [link](https://my.vertica.com/docs/CE/6.0.1/HTML/index.htm#4839.htm) for more loading techniques.
- 3- i would create a UDF to work with my layout.

Here is a [link](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#1639.htm) to get you started with Vertica UDF's(user defined functions).

**Place a real example for us(load type,tables,etc..) , maybe there is a simple fix ! for it !**

Comment: @DrewRose `MERGE` has high overhead. I would see if you could perform the data manipulation before it comes into Vertica. Otherwise, you can try using a temporary table. You can then lastly try using `MERGE`.

Answer (score 0):

Until we get further clarification on what your specific needs are, I would recommend creating a view that represents all or a subset of the data of the parent table. The results of the view would be obtained on the fly ensuring that the latest data is present.